# delete list item using QB SDK 12

Tags: quickbooks

Using QB SDK 12.0

I have a scenario where I create a new Employee and then a Sales Rep using the Employee ListID.

If I try to enter a Sales Rep that duplicates and existing Initial, the Sales Rep fails and then I want to delete the Employee.

I don't see how I can delete the Employee, or any List item (Customer, Vendor, etc) for that matter.  Is it possible, or do I have to mark them IsActive = False?

Rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ListDel to delete list objects (customers, vendors, employees, items, etc.).

The qbXML syntax is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="12.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <ListDelRq>
      <!-- ListDelType may have one of the following values: Account, BillingRate, Class, Currency, Customer, CustomerMsg, CustomerType, DateDrivenTerms, Employee, InventorySite, ItemDiscount, ItemFixedAsset, ItemGroup, ItemInventory, ItemInventoryAssembly, ItemNonInventory, ItemOtherCharge, ItemPayment, ItemSalesTax, ItemSalesTaxGroup, ItemService, ItemSubtotal, JobType, OtherName, PaymentMethod, PayrollItemNonWage, PayrollItemWage, PriceLevel, SalesRep, SalesTaxCode, ShipMethod, StandardTerms, ToDo, UnitOfMeasureSet, Vehicle, Vendor, VendorType, WorkersCompCode -->
      <ListDelType >ENUMTYPE</ListDelType> <!-- required -->
      <ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- required -->
    </ListDelRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

More qbXML examples:

- [QuickBooks qbXML example - deleting list objects](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_for_Deleting_%22List%22_Objects_%28Customers,_Vendors,_Items,_etc.%29)
- [QuickBooks qbXML examples](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests)